# How compress file content with ZF2 Filter?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, compression

How can I make a compressed archive from a local file with ZF2 `Zend\Filter\Compress`?

I wrote this code:

```
$filter = new Zend\Filter\Compress(array(
    'adapter' => 'Gz',
    'options' => array(
        'archive' => "/local/lnx/archive.gz",
    ),
));
$compressed = $filter->filter("/local/lnx/file.txt");
```

It make a new archive in `/local/lnx/` but it contain a file without extension that contain the string `/local/lnx/file.txt`. But I don't want that, I would like to have an archive that contain the FILE `file.txt` not its name. Where is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got this right then what's happening is that you're setting the archive content to be the string `/local/lnx/file.txt` and not the file that resides under that path. Take a look at the method [definition](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Filter/Compress.php#L202). It looks like you need to get the file contents (e.g. with [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function) and pass that to the filter method.